# Qt: QNetworkAccessManager dont send request

Tags: qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qeventloop

I used QNetworkAccessManager to handle send a http request:

```
void f()
{    
    QNetworkRequest request( QUrl( address ) );    
    QNetworkAccessManager mng;
    mng.get(request);
    //QEventLoop().exec();
    }
void main()
{
    ...
    f();
    ...
}
```

If without line QEventLoop().exec();, the app will not send request. But if with line QEventLoop().exec();, it will. I don't understan why?
Can you clear me?
Thank you very much!
(P/s: I have seen this link: [Sending an HTTP request using QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204621/sending-an-http-request-using-qnetworkaccessmanager))

Answer (score 0):

```
void f()    
{        
    static QNetworkRequest request( QUrl( address ) );        
    static QNetworkAccessManager mng;
    mng.get(request);
}
void main()
{
    ...
    f();
    ...
}
```

I think this is because QNetworkAccessManager is asynchronous and need the time to send the request. But require, url, query, ... is destroyed when out of scope.
-> we need in scope when QNetworkAccessManager do send request (use QEventLoop().exec(); ) or let require, url, query, ... is persistent (declare it with static).